# Open only one Tk.Toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

I bound the opening of a new window (Tk.Toplevel) on a button. However, if I press the button twice, two windows turn on.
Can I deactivate the button until the new window is turned off, or display a message box if I press the button twice ?

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: yes, you can deactivate button in function which you use to create `toplevel`. And you activate it back in function which `toplevel` uses to close it. OR you may create global variable `my_top = None` to keep created `toplevel` - and when you click second time then you create window only if `my_top` is still `None`. And when you close window then you assign again `my_top = None`. And this method can use for any object which has to be only one - not only window but ie. network socket, thread, bullet in game, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `disable/enable` button or you can assign `TopLevel` to global variable which at start has value `None` and you check if it is still `None` before creating window. if it is not `None` then don't create window. When you close window then you set it again `None`.

This method can be use for any object which can be only one at some moment - ie. bullet in game.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def close_top():
    global single_top

    single_top.destroy()
    single_top = None
    
def open_top():
    global single_top
    
    if single_top is None:
        single_top = tk.Toplevel(root)
        l = tk.Label(single_top, text='TopLevel')
        l.pack()    
        single_top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_top)
    else:
        print("Top level already exists")
    
# --- main ---

single_top = None

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text='TOP', command=open_top)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same structure with disabled button

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def close_top():

    single_top.destroy()

    b['state'] = 'normal'
    
def open_top():
    global single_top

    b['state'] = 'disable'
    
    single_top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    l = tk.Label(single_top, text='TopLevel')
    l.pack()    
    single_top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_top)
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text='TOP', command=open_top)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to import an external library. You can simply check if root contains any instance of `Toplevel` using `isinstance()`.

Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 


def top():
    
    if not any(isinstance(x, Toplevel) for x in root.winfo_children()):
            top = Toplevel(root)
            lbl = Label(top, text='TopLevel')
            lbl.pack()    
             
    else:
        
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Top level already exists")
        
    

root = Tk()

btn = Button(root, text='text', command=top)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you simply want to disable the button.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 


def top():

 
        btn['state'] = 'disabled'
        top = Toplevel(root)
        lbl = Label(top, text='TopLevel')
        lbl.pack()

        top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda : btn.configure(state='normal') or top.destroy())


                
root = Tk()

btn = Button(root, text='text', command=top)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```